# Mysql fetch from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

Fee Table....status 1 shows that the fee is common in all class...
    and status 2 is for uncommon fee................

```
+--------+------------------+-------------+--------+
| fee_id | fee_name         | duration_id | status |
+--------+------------------+-------------+--------+
|      1 | Admission Fee    |           4 |      1 |
|      2 | Re-admission Fee |           4 |      1 |
|      3 | Tuition Fee      |           1 |      1 |
|      4 | Computer Lab Fee |           1 |      2 |
|      5 | Science Lab Fee  |           1 |      2 |
|      6 | Exam Fee         |           2 |      1 |
|      7 | Electricity Fee  |           3 |      1 |
|      8 | Transport Fee    |           1 |      1 |
|      9 | Late Fee         |           1 |      1 |
+--------+------------------+-------------+--------+`
```

Class Table....................

```
+----------+------------+
| class_id | class_name |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | Nursery    |
|        2 | L.K.G      |
|        3 | U.K.G      |
|        4 | 1          |
|        5 | 2          |
|        6 | 3          |
|        7 | 4          |
|        8 | 5          |
|        9 | 6          |
|       10 | 7          |
|       11 | 8          |
|       12 | 9          |
|       13 | 10         |
+----------+------------+
```

`Here, I am mapping uncommon fee to class.

```
+----------+--------+
| class_id | fee_id |
+----------+--------+
|       10 |      4 |
|       10 |      5 |
|       11 |      4 |
|       11 |      5 |
|       12 |      4 |
|       12 |      5 |
|       13 |      4 |
|       13 |      4 |
+----------+--------+
```

I have to fetch fee_names for class id 10 including all the common fee and uncommon fee belongs to that class_id.

Comment: Show us your attempts to solve this task.

Comment: So you want all fees that are 1 and only the fees that are two defiend for class_id 10.  You can do this with a union or an 'or' statement and a left join.

Comment: Yeah... Plz share query for that... I'm a learner... I'm bot good in sal query

Comment: I want all the fee_name whose status is 1 as well as those fee_name whose fee_id belongs to class 10...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--This seems a bit complex to me but should be one way to do it. 
We get all records from fee and left join to class but only for class_ID 10.
we then only include records where the class_ID is null of the fee status is 1.

The only records having a class_ID in the class_Fee table would be 10.

```
SELECT Fee_name
FROM Fee
LEFT JOIN Class_fee CF
 on Fee.Fee_ID = CF.Fee_ID
 and class_ID = 10
WHERE (CF.Class_ID is not null OR Fee.Status = 1)
```

--A union approach seems more straight forward

```
SELECT Fee_name 
FROM Fee 
WHERE status = 1
UNION
SELECT Fee_Name 
FROM Fee 
INNER JOIN Class_Fee CF 
  on CF.Fee_ID= Fee.Fee_ID
WHERE Class_ID = 10
```

If you can guarantee that only status 2 records get mapped the union could be a union all to gain a bit of performance by avoiding the distinct.  or you could use the `union all` if duplicate names would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (if I understood correctly your request):

```
select f.fee_name from fee f join uncommon_class c where f.fee_id = c.fee_id                
and c.class_id=10 union select fee_name from fee where status =1
```

Comment: I don't see how.  f is alias of fee and f isn't referenced but the one time.